# Create new buildType for submodule based on parent project

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, groovy, build-system

I have and android project which has `buildTypes` configured for `release, debug, dev, stag`. I have a module which has `buildTypes` configured for `release, debug`. I want to add `dev` and `stag` buildType to my module while building the `dev` and `staging` build variant of app. I want to do this without adding any piece of code in the module. So that in future if I create new `buildTypes` or `flavours`, I don't have to go and change them in the individual module section. I should be able to control them either from app level or project level `build.gradle` file. Please help me out. I am beginner in Gradle build system. Thanks in advance.

I need something like thi:

```
implementation project(":sub_module"){
    android {
        buildTypes {
            dev {
                initWith debug
            }
            stag {
                initWith debug
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something like this, that I can configure from app/project level build.gradle file.